# Springboot Maven Application jar not running

Tags: eclipse, maven, jar, spring-boot

I am using springboot to build a restful application with maven it  run  on eclipse ,but not using jar file and cmd giving me this exception: `C:\restapi\BvmtRestApi\target>java -jar BvmtRestApi-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.javaadvent.bootrest.TodoAppConfig
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:89)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:46)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:58)`

Comment: How did you create your jar file? Looks like there are some classes missing in the jar file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below are the steps to run from jar

1. Add below maven build plugin.

   ```
   <build>
   <plugins>
       <plugin>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
       </plugin>
   </plugins>
   </build>
   ```
2. Run maven command 'mvn package' and it generates jar file with project_name in target directory.
3. Run the command java -jar target/project_name.jar from command line.

Answer (score 0):

right click on project
go to configure build path
then to libraries
and add all the jar missing from your project